# Yeoman webapp grunt file modification

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman

I am try to used yeoman webapp generator with compass to my next project. In my app folder structure as follows.

```
 app
 |-scripts
 |-styles
 |---global
 |-----components
 |---layout
 |---pages
 |---themes
```

So I want to build exact same structure after executing the grunt build command. No need to concatenate of minify css and js file. My modified grundfile is:

```
 // Generated on 2015-06-19 using
 // generator-webapp 0.5.1
 'use strict';

// # Globbing
// for performance reasons we're only matching one level down:
// 'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
// If you want to recursively match all subfolders, use:
// 'test/spec/**/*.js'

module.exports = function (grunt) {

// Time how long tasks take. Can help when optimizing build times
require('time-grunt')(grunt);

// Load grunt tasks automatically
require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

// Configurable paths
var config = {
    app: 'app',
    dist: 'dist'
};

// Define the configuration for all the tasks
grunt.initConfig({
    // Project settings
    config: config,
    // Watches files for changes and runs tasks based on the changed files
    watch: {
        bower: {
            files: ['bower.json'],
            tasks: ['wiredep']
        },
        js: {
            files: ['<%= config.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'],
            tasks: ['jshint'],
            options: {
                livereload: true
            }
        },
        jstest: {
            files: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js'],
            tasks: ['test:watch']
        },
        gruntfile: {
            files: ['Gruntfile.js']
        },
        compass: {
            files: ['<%= config.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
            tasks: ['compass:server']
        },
        styles: {
            files: ['<%= config.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
            tasks: ['newer:copy:styles']
        },
        livereload: {
            options: {
                livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
            },
            files: [
                '<%= config.app %>/{,*/}*.html',
                '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                '<%= config.app %>/images/{,*/}*'
            ]
        }
    },
    // The actual grunt server settings
    connect: {
        options: {
            port: 9000,
            open: true,
            livereload: 35729,
            // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside
            hostname: 'localhost'
        },
        livereload: {
            options: {
                middleware: function (connect) {
                    return [
                        connect.static('.tmp'),
                        connect().use('/plugins', connect.static('./plugins')),
                        connect.static(config.app)
                    ];
                }
            }
        },
        test: {
            options: {
                open: false,
                port: 9001,
                middleware: function (connect) {
                    return [
                        connect.static('.tmp'),
                        connect.static('test'),
                        connect().use('/plugins', connect.static('./plugins')),
                        connect.static(config.app)
                    ];
                }
            }
        },
        dist: {
            options: {
                base: '<%= config.dist %>',
                livereload: false
            }
        }
    },
    // Empties folders to start fresh
    clean: {
        dist: {
            files: [{
                    dot: true,
                    src: [
                        '.tmp',
                        '<%= config.dist %>/*',
                        '!<%= config.dist %>/.git*'
                    ]
                }]
        },
        server: '.tmp'
    },
    // Make sure code styles are up to par and there are no obvious mistakes
    jshint: {
        options: {
            jshintrc: '.jshintrc',
            reporter: require('jshint-stylish')
        },
        all: [
            'Gruntfile.js',
            '<%= config.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
            '!<%= config.app %>/scripts/vendor/*',
            'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
        ]
    },
    // Mocha testing framework configuration options
    mocha: {
        all: {
            options: {
                run: true,
                urls: ['http://<%= connect.test.options.hostname %>:<%= connect.test.options.port %>/index.html']
            }
        }
    },
    // Compiles Sass to CSS and generates necessary files if requested
    compass: {
        options: {
            sassDir: '<%= config.app %>/styles',
            cssDir: '.tmp/styles',
            imagesDir: '<%= config.app %>/images',
            javascriptsDir: '<%= config.app %>/scripts',
            fontsDir: '<%= config.app %>/styles/fonts',
            generatedImagesDir: '.tmp/images/generated',
            importPath: 'plugins',
            httpImagesPath: '../images',
            httpGeneratedImagesPath: '../images/generated',
            httpFontsPath: 'fonts',
            relativeAssets: false,
            assetCacheBuster: false
        },
        dist: {
            options: {
                generatedImagesDir: '<%= config.dist %>/images/generated'
            }
        },
        server: {
            options: {
                debugInfo: true
            }
        }
    },
    // Add vendor prefixed styles
 //autoprefixer: {
        //options: {
        //browsers: ['> 1%', 'last 2 versions', 'Firefox ESR', 'Opera 12.1']
      //},
      //dist: {
       // files: [{
          //expand: true,
          //cwd: '.tmp/styles/',
          //src: '{,*/}*.css',
          //dest: '.tmp/styles/'
        //}]
      //}
    //},

    // Automatically inject Bower components into the HTML file
    wiredep: {
        app: {
            ignorePath: /^\/|\.\.\//,
            src: ['<%= config.app %>/index.html'],
            exclude: ['plugins/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.js']
        },
        sass: {
            src: ['<%= config.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
            ignorePath: /(\.\.\/){1,2}plugins\//
        }
    },
    // Renames files for browser caching purposes
    rev: {
        dist: {
            files: {
                src: [
                    '<%= config.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
                    '<%= config.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                    '<%= config.dist %>/images/{,*/}*.*',
                    '<%= config.dist %>/styles/fonts/{,*/}*.*',
                    '<%= config.dist %>/*.{ico,png}'
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    // Reads HTML for usemin blocks to enable smart builds that automatically
    // concat, minify and revision files. Creates configurations in memory so
    // additional tasks can operate on them
    useminPrepare: {
        options: {
            dest: '<%= config.dist %>'
        },
        html: '<%= config.app %>/index.html'
    },
    // Performs rewrites based on rev and the useminPrepare configuration
    usemin: {
        options: {
            assetsDirs: [
                '<%= config.dist %>',
                '<%= config.dist %>/images',
                '<%= config.dist %>/styles'
            ]
        },
        html: ['<%= config.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
        css: ['<%= config.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css']
    },
    // The following *-min tasks produce minified files in the dist folder
    imagemin: {
        dist: {
            files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '<%= config.app %>/images',
                    src: '{,*/}*.{gif,jpeg,jpg,png}',
                    dest: '<%= config.dist %>/images'
                }]
        }
    },
    svgmin: {
        dist: {
            files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '<%= config.app %>/images',
                    src: '{,*/}*.svg',
                    dest: '<%= config.dist %>/images'
                }]
        }
    },
    htmlmin: {
        dist: {
            options: {
                collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
                collapseWhitespace: true,
                conservativeCollapse: true,
                removeAttributeQuotes: true,
                removeCommentsFromCDATA: true,
                removeEmptyAttributes: true,
                removeOptionalTags: true,
                removeRedundantAttributes: true,
                useShortDoctype: true
            },
            files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '<%= config.dist %>',
                    src: '{,*/}*.html',
                    dest: '<%= config.dist %>'
                }]
        }
    },
    // By default, your `index.html`'s <!-- Usemin block --> will take care
    // of minification. These next options are pre-configured if you do not
    // wish to use the Usemin blocks.
    // cssmin: {
    //   dist: {
    //     files: {
    //       '<%= config.dist %>/styles/main.css': [
    //         '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
    //         '<%= config.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'
    //       ]
    //     }
    //   }
    // },
    // uglify: {
    //   dist: {
    //     files: {
    //       '<%= config.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js': [
    //         '<%= config.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js'
    //       ]
    //     }
    //   }
    // },
    // concat: {
    //   dist: {}
    // },

    // Copies remaining files to places other tasks can use
    copy: {
        dist: {
            files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    dot: true,
                    cwd: '<%= config.app %>',
                    dest: '<%= config.dist %>',
                    src: [
                        '*.{ico,png,txt}',
                        'images/{,*/}*.webp',
                        '{,*/}*.html',
                        'styles/fonts/{,*/}*.*'
                    ]
                }, {
                    src: 'node_modules/apache-server-configs/dist/.htaccess',
                    dest: '<%= config.dist %>/.htaccess'
                }, {
                    expand: true,
                    dot: true,
                    cwd: '.',
                    src: 'plugins/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/fonts/bootstrap/*',
                    dest: '<%= config.dist %>'
                }, {
                    //for font-awesome
                    expand: true,
                    dot: true,
                    //cwd: 'plugins/font-awesome',
                    cwd: '.',
                    //src: ['fonts/*.*'],
                    src: 'plugins/fontawesome/fonts/*',
                    dest: '<%= config.dist %>'
                }, {
                    //for font-awesome
                    expand: true,
                    dot: true,
                    //cwd: 'plugins/font-awesome',
                    cwd: '.',
                    //src: ['fonts/*.*'],
                    src: 'plugins/slick.js/fonts/*',
                    dest: '<%= config.dist %>'
                }]
        },
        styles: {
            expand: true,
            dot: true,
            cwd: '<%= config.app %>/styles',
            dest: '.tmp/styles/',
            src: '{,*/}*.css'
        }
    },
    // Generates a custom Modernizr build that includes only the tests you
    // reference in your app
    modernizr: {
        dist: {
            devFile: 'plugins/modernizr/modernizr.js',
            outputFile: '<%= config.dist %>/scripts/vendor/modernizr.js',
            files: {
                src: [
                    '<%= config.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
                    '<%= config.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                    '!<%= config.dist %>/scripts/vendor/*'
                ]
            },
            uglify: true
        }
    },
    // Run some tasks in parallel to speed up build process
    concurrent: {
        server: [
            'compass:server',
            'copy:styles'
        ],
        test: [
            'copy:styles'
        ],
        dist: [
            'compass',
            'copy:styles',
            'imagemin',
            'svgmin'
        ]
    }
});


grunt.registerTask('serve', 'start the server and preview your app, --allow-remote for remote access', function (target) {
    if (grunt.option('allow-remote')) {
        grunt.config.set('connect.options.hostname', '0.0.0.0');
    }
    if (target === 'dist') {
        return grunt.task.run(['build', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);
    }

    grunt.task.run([
        'clean:server',
        'wiredep',
        'concurrent:server',
        //'autoprefixer',
        'connect:livereload',
        'watch'
    ]);
});

grunt.registerTask('server', function (target) {
    grunt.log.warn('The `server` task has been deprecated. Use `grunt serve` to start a server.');
    grunt.task.run([target ? ('serve:' + target) : 'serve']);
});

grunt.registerTask('test', function (target) {
    if (target !== 'watch') {
        grunt.task.run([
            'clean:server',
            'concurrent:test',
            //'autoprefixer'
        ]);
    }

    grunt.task.run([
        'connect:test',
        'mocha'
    ]);
});

grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'clean:dist',
    'wiredep',
    'useminPrepare',
    'concurrent:dist',
    //'autoprefixer',
    'concat',
    'cssmin',
    'uglify',
    'copy:dist',
    'modernizr',
    'rev',
    'usemin'
            //'htmlmin'
]);

grunt.registerTask('default', [
    'newer:jshint',
    'test',
    'build'
]);
```

};